# Regex break string into words, preserve digits but not dashes

Tags: regex, typescript

I'm looking for a regex string that I can pass into a typescript split function that will split up words and punctuation, but preserve numbers.

Example String:

```
SIZE 0.25 510-15 PSIG
```

I've tried just /\W/g, but then the period on "0.25" is captured

[image]

so then I added a negative lookahead:

```
/(\W)(?!\d+ )/g
```

But then the dash on "510-15" is not captured and I need it to be.

[image]

I'm looking for a regex match that would not split on a decimal point between two numbers, but would split on a dash between two numbers. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out.

By using an 'or' condition I was able to split on all dashes:

```
((\W)(?!\d+ )|-)
```

Comment: Mark your answer as the solution to the question. :-)

Comment: But remember that this will mess with negative numbers, if you need to support that.

Comment: @JeppeSpanggaard It says I have to wait 2 days before I can mark my own solution .

Comment: @Pianosaurus Thanks for pointing this out. In this case I do not need to exclude negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

`\W` is an alias for non-word characters (word-characters being `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`). Instead of using the alias, you can type it manually, and expand it as needed.

```js
"SIZE 0.25 510-15 PSIG".split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]/g)
```

> Output: `Array(5) [ "SIZE", "0.25", "510", "15", "PSIG" ]`

Note that you might want to combine it with your lookaheads if you want to make sure the dot is in a number, and that the dash is not in front of a number (if you need to support negative numbers).

Comment: You could use `[^\w.]`